# What is Symantec Auto-Protect

Tags: macos, mac, catalina, preferences, gatekeeper

I found some 3rd-party preference-panes in my macOS 10.15.7 Catalina, one is 'NTFS for MAC OS X' but I know what it is, the thing I want to know is 'Symantec Auto-Protect':
'SymantecSAQuickMenu.prefPane'
'SymAutoProtect.prefPane'

I am wondering if someone know what they are, I can't open them because 'System Preferences' says that it will harm my computer (Avast didn't mind when I scanned), it doesn't give a way to allow from 'Security & Privacy.'
Any luck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Symantec is the company who makes Norton Anti-Virus & also Symantec End-Point protection.

If you have another antivirus product on your Mac - Avast - then you should [completely uninstall Norton](https://support.norton.com/sp/en/us/home/current/solutions/kb20080427024142EN) &/or Symantec [Symantec may have been installed as part of a corporate package, in which case you'd need to check with the relevant IT department].

Having two live-scanning* antivirus products on one machine is bad - they can fight each other.

This doesn't include such as Malwarebytes Free, which does not live-scan.

Comment: Oh, thanks, I did not know it was related with Norton, yes I had Norton before. Then I think I can erase them now, as they are old and, my subscription ended. Thanks again!